# MongoDB Taking Too Long time in C#.net

Tags: mongodb, c#-4.0, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am  retrieving data  from mongoDB using C# driver, It is taking  a lot of time when i do to list Please help me

My Mongoquery  is

```
var documentReportIds = new BsonValue[] { LatestReportIds };
var documentChennelIds = new BsonValue[] { Cid };
var documentPropertyIds = new BsonValue[] { Pid };
IMongoQuery query = new QueryDocument();
query = Query.And(Query.GTE("CheckInDate", startdate.Date.AddMinutes(330)),
Query.LTE("CheckInDate", endDate.Date.AddMinutes(330)));
query = Query.And(query, Query.EQ("SubscriberPropertyId", reportFilter.SubscriberPropertyId));
query = Query.And(query, Query.EQ("LengthOfStay", reportFilter.LOS));
query = Query.And(query, Query.In("ReportId", documentReportIds));
query = Query.And(query, Query.In("ChannelId", documentChennelIds));
query = Query.And(query, Query.In("PropertyId", documentPropertyIds));

 MongoDBEntities<ScheduleOptimizationReportDetails> _obj = new MongoDBEntities<ScheduleOptimizationReportDetails>();
 var list= _obj.GetSchedularOptimizationJoin(query);
```

Class from  where it  perform data retrieving

```
public class MongoDBEntities<T>
{
   MongoDatabase db = MongoDBInstance.GetMongoDatabase; 
 public List GetSchedularOptimizationJoin(IMongoQuery query)
 {
 MongoCollection MCollection = db.GetCollection(“Subscription_OptimisedReports”);
 MongoCursor cursor = MCollection.FindAs(query).SetFields(Fields.Include(“ScheduleLogId”, “SubscriberPropertyId”, “CheckInDate”, “ReportId”, “CreatedDate”));
 List entities = cursor.ToList();
 return entities ;
}
}
```

what is another option to select data in C#,  I have  also applied indexing on column.

Please help me how to solve it.

Comment: what version of C# driver are you using? there use to be a bug in C# driver 1.8.0 which slows down the `ToList()` function of cursor. It's supposed to be fixed in versions later than 1.8.3.

Comment: I am using  **1.9.1.221**  version of c# driver  but it also slow even with **1000 records**

Comment: So with this query, how many documents are supposed to be selected?

Comment: It will Select Around **100000** documents from **8 crores** documents in mobgoDB

Comment: if it's 100000 documents, it will be slow, it's normal. make sure you have enough memory to fit them in, otherwise the system's going to swap memory with disk, which makes it even slower. Do you really need those 100000 documents? nobody would read that many data.

Comment: I guess the last thing you can do is to check the indexes, maybe call the `explain()` in shell to see how it's executed.

Comment: this is  my indexes

  {"v" : 1,"key" : {"SubscriberPropertyId" : 1,"CheckInDate" : 1},
                "name" : "SubscriberPropertyId_1_CheckInDate_1"}
     {"v" : 1,
                "key" : {"ReportId" : 1,"PropertyId" : 1,"ChannelId" : 1,"LengthOfStay" : 1,"Restriction" : 1},
                "name" : "ReportId_1_PropertyId_1_ChannelId_1_LengthOfStay_1_triction_1"}
    {"v" : 1,
                "key" : {"CheckInDate" : 1},
                "name" : "CheckInDate_1"}

Comment: Whenever posting performance question, include the output of `explain()`. Don't post code in comments, edit your question instead. As for the query, never put the range query first, always the equality queries.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [MongoDB.Driver.Linq](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver.html) package to help you create your querys with Linq expressions.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.